# Bootstrap 4: put inputs horizontal

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am new in Bootstrap 4 and need some help. I want that my first two inputfiels are at the same line (horizontal) and not among themselves. Like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wm7lX.jpg)

Here is my HTML code:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">         
      <div class="form-group col-md-6 offset-md-3">             
        <input class="form-control transparent-input" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
      </div>        
      <div class="form-group col-md-6 offset-md-3">
        <input class="form-control transparent-input" type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Vorname" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6 offset-md-3">
        <textarea class="form-control transparent-input" cols="20" rows="10" placeholder="Enter your message"></textarea>              
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6 offset-md-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
        <!--<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send invitation</button>-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: change col-md-6 to col-md-3 for the first two divs, play a bit around css and bootstrap is always a little bit of trying (at least in the beginning)

Comment: @misanthrop
it worked! thank you!

Comment: This is literally in the documentation of bootstrap: [forms](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/#form-grid)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way. I hope you will get your desired style.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <input class="form-control transparent-input" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <input class="form-control transparent-input" type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Vorname" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <textarea class="form-control transparent-input" cols="20" rows="10" placeholder="Enter your message"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```